# Ensure element is always on top

Tags: javascript, html

I'm building a very simple Chrome extension that will put a clickable image on top of any `youtube.com` page.

The image shows up and has its intended click-functionality, but it is layered below any other elements that appear on the page. This is my code:

```
const linkItem = document.createElement("a");
linkItem.href="https://www.youtube.com/";
linkItem.innerHTML = "<img src='https://imgur.com/gBgwnSa.png' title='YouTube Home'>";
linkItem.setAttribute("style", "position:absolute;top:50px;left:200px;");

document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].appendChild(linkItem);
```

The position is just a placeholder.

How can I set the image to always appear layered above any other elements of the page (preferably without having to create a CSS style sheet)? I know this is a beginner question, but any help would be greatly appreciated! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the "z-index" property on CSS. You just have to set it to a value high enough, and it'll always be over everything else that have a smaller/null z-index set.

In this case:

```
linkItem.setAttribute("style", "position:absolute;top:50px;left:200px;z-index:99");
```